# How should i code to get the correct ID of diary in Diary Table？

Tags: android, android-room

I want realize when longclick any RecyclerView item will pop-up DialogFragment function. The DialogFragment wiil be used to edit Diary, so I should find out the Diary ID. In the begining, I find the id from the RecyclerView position, Because item id is only one off the value of  Diary id. **But the program crashed after deleting any diary when I longclick the item due to the ID is wrong!**
Such as, now there are have 2 diary here and there Diary id in Diary table is 1,2 and there postion in RecyclerView is 0,1. If i delete the first Diary, the Second Diary's position is 0 in RecyclerView.

In the begining, I coded these to realize the function likes the Image:

```
RecyclerView rv_diary = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_diary_write_view);
        final DiaryListAdapter adapter_diary = new DiaryListAdapter(new DiaryListAdapter.DiaryDiff(), new DiaryListAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(int pos) {
                Position = pos+1;
                mDiaryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(activity).get(DiaryViewModel.class);
                mDiaryViewModel.getSpecificDiary(pos+1).observe(activity, diary -> {
                    Bundle result = new Bundle();
                    result.putInt("bundle_specific_nu", pos+1);
                    result.putString("bundle_specific_title", String.valueOf(diary.getDiary_Title()));
                    result.putString("bundle_specific_content", String.valueOf(diary.getDiary_Content()));
                    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("requestSpecificDiary",result);
                });
                DWUpdDiaFragment dwUpdDiaFragment = new DWUpdDiaFragment();
                dwUpdDiaFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),"dwUpdDiaFragment");
            }
        });
        rv_diary.setAdapter(adapter_diary);
        rv_diary.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
        mDiaryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(activity).get(DiaryViewModel.class);
        mDiaryViewModel.getAllDiariesLive().observe(activity, diaries -> {
            adapter_diary.submitList(diaries);
        });
```

Then i wiil get Diary title and Diry content in DWUpdDiaFragment/

```
public class DWUpdDiaFragment extends DialogFragment {

    TextView tv_view_nu;
    EditText et_view_title,et_view_content;
    FloatingActionButton fab_update,fab_back;

    String get_title,get_content;
    int get_nu;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_diary_write_view_and_update, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        tv_view_nu = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_diary_write_view_and_update_nu);
        et_view_title = view.findViewById(R.id.et_diary_write_view_and_update_title);
        et_view_content = view.findViewById(R.id.et_diary_write_view_and_update_content);
        fab_back = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_fg_diary_write_and_update_back);
        fab_update = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_fg_diary_write_and_update_find_out);

        getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("requestSpecificDiary", this, new FragmentResultListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle result) {
                get_nu = result.getInt("bundle_specific_nu");
                get_title = result.getString("bundle_specific_title");
                get_content = result.getString("bundle_specific_content");
                Log.d("test",get_title + get_content);
                tv_view_nu.setText("Diary " + get_nu + " Edit Page");
                et_view_title.setText(get_title);
                et_view_content.setText(get_content);
            }
        });

        fab_update.setOnClickListener(update -> {
            Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString("bundle_update_title", String.valueOf(et_view_title.getText()));
            result.putString("bundle_update_content", String.valueOf(et_view_content.getText()));
            Log.d("test","\nready been sent" + et_view_title.getText() + et_view_content.getText());
            getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("updateSpecificDiary", result);
            dismiss();
        });

        fab_back.setOnClickListener(back -> {
            dismiss();
        });

        return  builder.create();
    }
}
```

Obviously, it is not a good solution to find the Diary ID through thess code. As a beginer, what should I code next? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your `DiaryViewModel` class, just add a property called `id` and set it to diary_id.